# How to write pixels in a pixel screen?

Tags: assembly, embedded

I have to write in order, pixels in a pixel screen, the address is from 8000H to 807FH, and I don't know how to do it.

I tried to ADD 1H in the address 8000H and a pixel appeared. So I tried in the next address 8010H, another pixel appeared but far away.... What I need is to know how to write 2 pixels one after the other.

Comment: Which CPU are you coding for?  Also, the next address after 8000H is 8001H, not 8010H.  That's 16 bytes away from the original address.

Comment: Which microprocessor? Which device? Is the screen monochrome? If not, how many colours does it have?

Comment: I'm using a small processor: PEPE-16

Comment: The screen is monochrome.... I have a programm that simulates the processor and the pixel screen, When I look to the memmory file it shows this:

Comment: 8000
8010
8020
8030
8040
8050
8060
8070
8080
8090
80A0
80B0

Comment: aren't they just the addresses, not the data?

Comment: So when you do `ADD 3H` (2+1) to the contents of address `8000H` do you get two pixels next to each other ? If so, the display is bitmapped, one _bit_ (not _byte_) per pixel, hence there's a total of 1024 pixels (`80H == 128` bytes `== 1024` bits). There'd be 128 pixels separating `8000H` and `8010H`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pixels must be arranged in some systematic way. Hopefully they are arranged horizontally which is nice and simple, but I once used a computer where they were arranged vertically, then the bytes were arranged horizontally in rows, then the rows were arranged vertically again, which was annoying to program.

Anyway, presumably one bit equals one pixel, because it's monochrome. So you just need to modify different bits and figure out which bit corresponds with which pixel.

To toggle the LSB of a byte you would XOR the byte with 1. To set it you would OR it with 1. To toggle the MSB you would XOR the byte with 128. If you don't know what the MSB and LSB are you need to read up on them and on bit manipulation.

Comment: meanwhile i started to experiment some things and the program now showes one pixel in order, one life after the other. but know i can get how to change column

Comment: ;[It's this]

pixel_screen:
MOV R9, 8000H